# Search String for Row Value MYSQL

Tags: mysql

This is a simple question, I'm sure if I phrased it right it's been asked here before, but I couldn't find it...

SO... here is my question.

I have a table of names:

```
+-----------+------------+
|   ID      |    NAME    |
+-----------+------------+
|   1       |    BOB     |
+-----------+------------+
|   2       |   NANCY    |
+-----------+------------+
|   3       |   FRED     |
+-----------+------------+
```

I would like to return rows that exist within a string:

"Bob and Jane went to the store to meet Fred"  Would return rows 1 and 3.

In my brain something like `SELECT ID FROM names WHERE name IN('bob and jane went to the store to meet fred');` Obviously it doesn't.  What's the proper type of query for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in MySQL

```
SELECT ID
FROM names
WHERE ' bob and jane went to the store to meet fred ' like concat('% ',name,' %')
```

The + operator will cast operands on both sides to numeric, which is really not what you want. Also, do you want Boby returned for Bob and Frederick for Fred?  If not, you need the spaces in the `concat` as well as wrapped around the string that you pass in to search with.

Comment: you are 100% correct.  this worked perfectly.  I'd actually found the concat version, a_horse_with_no_name got me started in the right direction.